# Google JS API Giving 403 Errors After OAuth is Successful

Tags: google-api

I'm using the Google Javascript API to access the Google Tasks and Google+ data via Oauth2. It works when I use my local host.

When I moved the code to my corporate server I am getting errors. I can authenticate with OAuth but when I try to make an API call after that I am seeing:

> 403 Forbidden: "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."

However, when I go into the developer console this project has both the Tasks and Google+ APIs enabled. Then I have a client_id for the FQD of my server. When this was not correct it was giving me an origin_mismatch but I resolved that.

I have generated a Server API key the same way I did for my localhost, but used the correct IP Address. I was also able to get a Client API (with no referrer restriction) key to work locally but not from the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried completely removing the IP restriction to where it said any IP had access but still getting a 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had originally generated a server API key and then made changes to the restrictions for the app. It seems that sometimes changes don't get added to an already generated API key. The fix was to generate a new server API key.